# Gallery plugin position moves on resize

Tags: html, css

i have a Gallery plugin on the main page that keeps moving when i resize the window or zoom in/out..

I cant pinpoint the exact rule for it to stay put. tried absolute and relative and fixed and static..it keeps moving.

the css rule:

```
.box_skitter {position:relative;width:800px;height:300px;background:#000;right:442px;margin-top:52px;margin-bottom:32px;}

www.tranceil.fm
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the position options position/right in skitter.styles.css and add margin auto for the horizontal position

```
.box_skitter {
  width: 985px;
  height: 560px;
  margin: 52px auto 32px;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Don't remove `position:relative;` - that makes sure the absolutely positioned child elements are positioned correctly.

Comment: Thanx for the help m8... finally it works, but the nav' numbers took off to the top left corner of the page?

Comment: Yup..the relative was necessary indeed :) thank you very much guys!!